# adding multiple drop down list to action bar in android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

i create an action bar in android with  a drop down list  to the action bar but the problem is that i want to add multiple drop down list that will always be displayed in the action bar

what it is displayed is one dropdown but the toast message display the selection of 2 selected items

## mainActivity.java

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbardropdownnavigation;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    /** An array of strings to populate dropdown list */
    String[] actions = new String[] {
        "Bookmark",
        "Subscribe",
        "Share"
    };

    String[] social = new String[] {
            "facebook",
            "twitter",
            "lamelchamel"
        };



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        /** Create an array adapter to populate dropdownlist */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, social);


        /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        /** Defining Navigation listener */
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected : " + actions[itemPosition] + " and you selected " + social[itemPosition]  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        };

        /** Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar */
        getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);

        getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter2, navigationListener);
    }
}
```

## main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

can anyone help me  with this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a menu file where you specify items and then in item's `actionLayout` specify your dropdown or spinner,

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/one"
          android:icon="@drawable/one"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:title="@null"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:onClick="onGroupItemClick"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/another"  />
</menu>
```

**another.xml**

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/order" />
```

This is a more rigid approach in this case and is suggested, rather then creating array by code just populate them from an `xml` if they are constant data but if it is dynamic then you have to do this by code creating an array.

Both ways you should go by the xml appoach for your menus in actionbar.

Comment: @ prateek so u mean i need to inflate the menu in .java file from the menu.xml ??? and what about the second file (another.xml) how to use it in my code ???

Comment: @LebDev You can check in menu.xml that inside my actionlayout I have specified the action to another this is nothing but another.xml